# Could not find icon null

Tags: javascript, css, react-redux, font-awesome-5

I am quite new at this and I have faced the following issue:

I have created my own fonts from fontAwesome in a class like this:

```
import {
  faArrowDown as fasArrowDown,
  faArrowLeft as fasArrowLeft,
  faBox as fasBox,
  faCheck as fasCheck,
  faCircle as fasCircle,
  faExchangeAlt as fasExchangeAlt,
  faTimes as fasTimes,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

import { faCircle as farCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
export const getSendBack = (
  order,
  canSendBack,
  sendBackOrder,
  formatMessage
) => ({
  id: 'sendBack',
  dataTestId: 'button-context-send-back',

  iconSendBack: 'fa-layers fa-3x fa-fw',
  iconSendBackTransform1: 'down-5 right-8 shrink-3',
  iconSendBackTransform2: 'down-5 right-8 shrink-5',
  iconSendBackTransform3: 'down-5 right-8 shrink-10',
  iconFasBoxSendBack: fasBox,
  iconFarCircleSendBack: farCircle,
  iconFasCircleSendBack: fasCircle,
  iconFasArrowLeft: fasArrowLeft,
  disabled: !canSendBack(order),
  titleSendBack: 'SEND BACK',
  title: formatMessage(terms.send_back),
  popup: {
    onOk: () => sendBackOrder(order.id),
    text: formatMessage(terms.send_back_order_question),
    title: formatMessage(terms.send_back),
  },
})
```

Then I used the objects in the class in another file like this:

```
<span
 className={b.iconSendBack}
>
<FontAwesomeIcon
 icon={b.iconFasCircleSendBack}
 mask={b.iconFasBoxSendBack}
 transform={b.iconSendBackTransform1}
/>
<FontAwesomeIcon
 icon={b.iconFarCircleSendBack}
 transform={b.iconSendBackTransform2}
/>
<FontAwesomeIcon
 icon={b.iconFasArrowLeft}
 transform={b.iconSendBackTransform3}
/>
</span>
```

Everything complies just fine and I can see the font that I want, the only issue is that I get the following warning in the console which says "Could not find icon null"

[image]

Can you please advice what the issue is and how to fix it? Does it gave anything to do with prefix or library?

Comment: There's no "null" icon on Font Awesome Library

Comment: Is this issue fixeD?